# Spring Exception handling with @ControllerAdvice provides centralized control but we have to add all throws exception in method signature

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

### Spring Exception handling with @ControllerAdvice provides centralised control but we have to add all throws exception in method signature

> for example
>
> ```
>  public void methodA() throws feign.FeignException,IOException,InterruptedException,ExecutionException{
>    //CODE
> }
> ```

```
ExceptionHandler
@ControllerAdvice
public class SpringExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value={feign.FeignException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMsg> handleFeignException(Exception ex, WebRequest request){
     //CODE..
}
@ExceptionHandler(value={TimeoutException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMsg> handleTimeoutException(Exception ex, WebRequest request){
     //CODE..
}
@ExceptionHandler(value={Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMsg> handleGenericException(Exception ex, WebRequest request){
     //CODE..
}
}
```

Is this the recommended approach to add all throws exceptions to be in method signature?
Please let me know if there is a better or suggested approach to declare throws Exceptions.

> **I have no issue with this approach but spring boot code/API Method**
>   **signature looks different or lengthy.**

Comment: There is no other way, those are Java language exception mechanisms, nothing to do with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw exceptions from wherever you like - inside method if a pre condition fails

https://github.com/dhananjay12/learning-spring-rest/blob/master/error-handling/src/main/java/com/djcodes/spring/rest/errorhandling/EmployeeController.java

or in the method signature.

Handling Feignexception could be a bit tricky. I suggest you to read this article  -https://source.coveo.com/2016/02/19/microservices-and-exception-handling/